# Which equation has a solution $(x,y)$ i which both $x$ and $y$ are integers?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Which equation has a solution $(x,y)$ in which both $x$ and $y$ are integers?

$12x + 9y = 16$

$32 x + 80y = 27$

$42x + 56y = -28$

$20x + 90y = 105$

Do we have to use discriminant ($b^2 - 4ac)$ and see which equation has two solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of [Bezout's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), namely,
$$ax+by = c$$
where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$, has integer solutions if and only if $\gcd(a,b) \vert c$.

Comment: Thanks. So, the correct answer is 42x + 56y= − 28